# @ in Anonymous method for Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Do you need to put @ before every property of the new anonymous type in Html.BeginForm?  Other than things like @id what if you have other properties..custom, do you need to add @ for each?  I found that for some for whatever reason if I add @ the compiler doesn't recognize that property and if I take it out it does...weird.

Example:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("GetFileUrl", "Content", FormMethod.Get, new { carId = Model.CarId, userId = Model.UserId, @carFileName = carFile.FileName }))
```

my action method is expecting params carId, userId, and carFileName

my route has `Cars/{userId}/{carId}/{carFileName}`

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to.  Can you show a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably referring to something you have seen in the anonymous `htmlAttributes` in p.e. the HtmlHelper.
You might have seen something like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link", "index", new { name = "peter" }, new { @class="myclass" })
```

You can use the `@` for reserved keywords like `string @string = "test"` or in my example `@class`. Normally you should avoid using reserved keywords like that, however in this case it is unavoidable.

To answer your question: Only use it for reserved keywords.